# What's the best way to convert all non-latin characters to a dash '-' in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build seo friendly urls, but the rails parameterize method just ignores non-latin characters. Problem there is that a chinese name results in nothing, breaking the friendly URLs.

How can I use parameterize and deal with this use case?

Thanks

Comment: This post: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/128 says that `gsub(/_|\W/, '-')` would do that... does it help?